# Fazer comparação de Valores MySQL Select

Tags: mysql

Possuo uma tabela com quatro colunas, sendo a primeira com um tipo, a segunda com o valor minimo , a terceira com o valor max, e a quarta com o dado que eu quero.
Preciso selecionar o valor da quarta coluna quando o tipo estiver na tabela e o valor informado estiver entre o valor máximo e mínimo, tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

`SELECT VALOR FROM TABELA WHERE TIPO = 1 AND MINIMO <=0.3 AND MAXIMO >= 0.3;`

```
TIPO    MINIMO  MAXIMO  VALOR
1       0       0,15    0
1       0,2     0,29    8,1
1       0,3     0,54    7,97
1       0,55    5       7,42
```

Para a tabela acima, o valor deveria ser 7,97, porém não da certo. Se tento trocar o 0.3 por 0.31, consigo o resultado desejado.

Comment: Simulei seus dados e não houve nenhum problema... [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fd40/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha tabela está com os campo MAXIMO, MININO e TIPO no tipo FLOAT, e para comparação do modo que desejo, este formato não é interessante, de acordo com o link
[Problemas com tipo Float](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/pt/problems-with-float.html) . A solução foi simples, como esses valores devem possuir 4 dígitos, sendo 2 decimais, fiz a troca do campo para DECIMAL(4,2), onde a comparação ocorre de maneira eficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar o comando *between*.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém o problema persiste.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT VALOR FROM TABELA WHERE ((TIPO = 1) AND (0.3 BETWEEN MINIMO AND MAXIMO))
```